# VBA web scraping retaining information from previous rows using Excel and Internet Explorer

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

Using VBA and Internet explorer in a loop with multiple rows (50K +).

I enter a value from Column A in a search box on a website from excel.

Page loads and Results are scraped into the same excel file: Columns B, C, D... for that row.

This is repeated for every entry in Column A.

The problem I encounter is when the webpage does not have an element to copy for Column D (VBA or Internet explorer; not sure which) is populating the cell (3D) with the previous rows data (2D).

Excel output example, there should be no duplication of names:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEXal.png

I have tried several options to name a few to clear the information:

```
ApplicationCutCopyMode = False
IE = Clear;
IE = Empty;
IF - Then statements
```

It continues to retain the value for the previous row for each cell until it is re-populated by a new element.

How can I purge/clear the information before each new loop?

Many thanks for your potential solutions, in advance. The code was based on this video link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=docnLSdj8rI

```
Sub  scrapyscrapy()

Dim IE As Object
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Visible = False
IE.FullScreen = False
IE.navigate "https://website"

Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now)
Loop
        
Set doc = IE.document

For IntRow = 2 To 100

    On Error Resume Next (as there are many missing elements depending on webpage)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    IE.document.querySelector("#Element").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range ("A" & IntRow).Value     
    IE.document.querySelector("#Element").Click
    IE.document.getElementsByClassName("button").Item(0).Click
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now)
    
    Str1 = IE.document.querySelector("#Element")
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & IntRow).Value = str1
    'If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & IntRow).Value = "" Then ‘ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & IntRow).Value = "--" (Band aid code to fill cells that were being populated with the value in the above cell)
    
    Str2 = IE.document.querySelector("#Element").innerText
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & IntRow).Value = str2
    'If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & IntRow).Value = "" Then 'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & IntRow).Value = "--" (Band aid code to fill cells that were being populated with the value in the above cell)
    
    Str3 = IE.document.querySelector("#Element").innerText
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & IntRow).Value = str3
    'If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & IntRow).Value = "" Then 'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & IntRow).Value = "--" (Band aid code to fill cells that were being populated with the value in the above cell)
    
    Str4 = IE.document.querySelector("#Element").innerText
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & IntRow).Value = str4
    'If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & IntRow).Value = "" Then 'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & IntRow).Value = "--" (Band aid code to fill cells that were being populated with the value in the above cell)
    
    Str5 = IE.document.querySelector("Element").innerText
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & IntRow).Value = str5
    'If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & IntRow).Value = "" Then 'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & IntRow).Value = "--" (Band aid code to fill cells that were being populated with the value in the above cell)
    
  
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now) (when new webpage is needed)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Next

ThisWorkbook.Save
IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I purge/clear the information before each new loop?

**Easiest way:**

Assign the variable(s) the value vbNullString before the `Next` e.g.

```
    '...... other code
    str3 = vbNullString
Next
```

---

**Cleaner way:**

Test whether the matched node `Is Nothing` (i.e. not present). Return the desired attribute if present else return `vbNullString`.

You could write a helper function to do this. Pass in the current node and the desired attribute to retrieve e.g. `innerText`.

One could then remove the variables completely, and that ghastly unclosed `On Error Resume Next`, and see if there are any other horrors in the code basement to deal with.

```
Public Sub scrapyscrapy()
    
    '''other code
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & IntRow).value = GetAttributeValue(IE.document.querySelector("#Element"), "innerText")
    '''other code

    Next
    ''' other code
End Sub

Public Function GetAttributeValue(ByVal node As Object, ByVal attributeName As String) As Variant

    Dim attributeValue As Variant

    If Not node Is Nothing Then attributeValue = CallByName(node, attributeName, VbGet)

    GetAttributeValue = attributeValue

End Function
```

Comment: It's an outstanding function to get rid of IndexError, AttributeError and stuff.

Comment: I've gone for the easy option in the first instance as there are 167 str variables and the cleaner option will take a bit of time. It worked. Awesome, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should work I hope, and is a bit neater. I've just shown the part that collects the 5 items.

```
Dim A(1,5)
Dim i
A(1,1)=IE.document.querySelector("#Element")
If A(1,1)<>"" Then 'keep going if first element exists
  For i=2 to 5
    A(1,i)=IE.document.querySelector("#Element").innerText
  Next I
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & IntRow).resize(1,5) = A
End If
```